# SSIS migration: split one record to many tables

Tags: ssis

I'm refactoring my db's User object from a schema that combines BillingAddress with Shipping Address:

```
[BillingFirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[BillinglastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[BillingAddress] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[BillingCity] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[BillingZip] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
[BillingState] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
[shippingFirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[shippingLastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[shippingAddress] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[shippingCity] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[shippingState] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
[shippingZip] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[shippingPhone] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
```

Refactored to one table for User and a separate table for addresses bound by a foreign key Users.ID => Addresses.idUser

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addresses](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Type] [nchar](10) NOT NULL, // designates Billing or Shipping
[Formatted] [nchar](600) NOT NULL,
[Street] [nchar](100) NOT NULL,
[City] [nchar](100) NOT NULL,
[POBox] [nchar](50) NULL,
[Region] [nchar](50) NULL,
[PostalCode] [nchar](50) NULL,
[Country] [nchar](50) NULL,
[ExtendedAddress] [nchar](100) NULL,
[idUser] [int] NULL,
```

How do I tell SSIS to import a record to the simplified User object and then create 2 addresses records; one with the Shipping info and the other with Billing?

I'd want preserve existing ID Key.

thx

Answer (score 1):

1. Multicast your source data.
2. Add a Derived Column component to each output stream. In your mind, designate one as the "Billing Address" stream and one as the "Shipping Address" stream.
3. Add a new column named "Type", hardcoded to "Billing" and "Shipping", respectively.
4. Add a destination component to each streams both pointing to your Address table.
5. Map the appropriate columns in each stream (ie BillingCity to the City in the "billing address" stream, ShippingCountry to the Country in the "shipping address" stream, etc.)